# HTML manipulation Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I build a server set sits between a client and a server - a relay server:

client <--> "my Server" <--> actual server

"My Server" is forwarding any request from the client to the "actual Server". Afterwards "my Server" is manipulating the response I get from the "actual Server" (I am translating text from german to english) and sending it back to the client.

So far so good. Everything is working fine. At least when I am not manipulating the HTML that I am getting from the "actual Server".

When I am manipulating it I get the error in the client:

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.

**edit:** to make sure that I don't mess up some encodings I only replaced some real "text". In my HTML there is a word called "KUNDE".

I did simple string replace: content = content.Replace("KUNDE", "CUSTOMER")

This way a made sure that I don't manipulate some real HTML markup because the word "KUNDE" is not part of the HTML markup

Any pointers why the error is occuring and how to fix it?

Comment: What is the original and altered markup? And how is the actual process working? This could range from bad characters in the markup to errors in WebMethods, so we'll likely need more info.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I manipulated only text, no HTML markup. I edited my post to clarify what I did

Comment: See [possible explanations](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it) from its creator...

Comment: thanks for your reply. the sollutions described only apply for people who have written their Ajax themselfs. The html I get from "actual server" works when I am not modifying it